# Too many values to unpack error in for loop counting values in list

Tags: python, python-3.x

In Python 3 I am trying to count then number of rating in this csv file, I have it pulling into a list, but when I try to actually start manipulating the data in a list I'm getting errors that I have too many values to unpack (expected 5) on my for loop and I don't know why.

```
with open(r'C:\Users\t_goo\Pictures\coding\dataset\smartphone- 
review\amazon_alexa.csv', mode='r') as alexa:

data = list(alexa.read().split(","))
print(data)

# rating, date, variation, review, feedback
for rating, data, variation, review, feedback in data:
    rating = rating.count()
    print(rating)
```

When I try to run this I get the following error:

```
line 7, in <module>
for rating, data, variation, review, feedback in data:
ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 5)
```

Here is a sample of the raw data:

> ```
> rating,date,variation,verified_reviews,feedback
> 5,31-Jul-18,Charcoal Fabric,Love my Echo!,1
> 5,31-Jul-18,Charcoal Fabric,Loved it!,1
> ```

Answer (score 1):

> `data = list(alexa.read().split(","))`

reads the whole file at once and splits it at `,` - you need to split the file first into lines and then *every line* on commas, so you need to do

```
data = [y.strip().split(",") for y in alexa.splitlines() if y.strip()]
```

which will result in a list of lists.

You can then use

```
for rating, data, variation, review, feedback in data:
    pass
```

to operate on it

Comment: @Tom fixed I hope